# Register a type at runtime using Unity Container

Tags: c#, types, unity-container, ioc-container

Why can I not do this? Where obj value is a valid type.

```
Type type = obj.Value.GetType();
this.unityContainer.RegisterType<type>();
```

OR

```
this.unityContainer.RegisterType(obj.Value);
```

When I can do this... where obj value would be the same type but known at compile time.

```
this.unityContainer.RegisterType<object, actualType>("Name");
```

The end goal of mine is to be able to register several different types at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything in angle brackets must be known at compile time - generics are a compile-time feature.  There are plenty of overloads of RegisterType that take a runtime-determined Type object such as you are doing here.

Move your runtime type reference out of the angle brackets and into the parentheses.

```
this.unityContainer.RegisterType(obj.Value.GetType());
```

Comment: typing error on the last part.

Comment: Ahh. the second way did work. I never resolved it though before using it. Thanks a ton for the info!